# passwd results in signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation

Tags: ubuntu, passwd

On Ubuntu 18.04 I am attempting to change my password with

```
sudo passwd myusername
```

I enter the new password and get this:

```
    Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7f38473d9426]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x7f3844f0b095, 0x2a)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x83
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:372 +0x292

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x7f3844f00ce0, 0xc420123b50, 0xc4200bc1a0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x66 fp=0xc420123b20 sp=0xc420123ae8 pc=0x7f3844da76a6
github.com/google/fscrypt/crypto._Cfunc_strlen(0x0, 0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:177 +0x4c fp=0xc420123b50 sp=0xc420123b20 pc=0x7f3844eb924c
github.com/google/fscrypt/crypto.NewKeyFromCString(0x0, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/crypto/key.go:192 +0x31 fp=0xc420123b90 sp=0xc420123b50 pc=0x7f3844ebabd1
main.Chauthtok.func1(0xc4200f85a0, 0x7f3844e02e00, 0x1, 0xc420123c38, 0x7f3844dce8b6)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/pam_fscrypt/pam_fscrypt.go:240 +0xad fp=0xc420123bd0 sp=0xc420123b90 pc=0x7f3844effcfd
github.com/google/fscrypt/actions.getWrappingKey(0xc4200f85a0, 0xc4200ae6c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/actions/callback.go:73 +0x71 fp=0xc420123c48 sp=0xc420123bd0 pc=0x7f3844ec1f61
github.com/google/fscrypt/actions.unwrapProtectorKey(0xc4200f85a0, 0xc4200ae6c0, 0xc420158020, 0x1a, 0x0)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/actions/callback.go:90 +0xd1 fp=0xc420123ce8 sp=0xc420123c48 pc=0x7f3844ec2211
github.com/google/fscrypt/actions.(*Protector).Unlock(0xc4200c3ba0, 0xc4200ae6c0, 0x1, 0x0)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/actions/protector.go:221 +0x51 fp=0xc420123d28 sp=0xc420123ce8 pc=0x7f3844ec4281
main.Chauthtok(0xc4200c29c0, 0xc4200b2840, 0x0, 0x0)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/pam_fscrypt/pam_fscrypt.go:252 +0x22f fp=0xc420123da8 sp=0xc420123d28 pc=0x7f3844efe66f
main.RunPamFunc(0x7f38451a6ae8, 0x5639f704f110, 0xc400000000, 0x5639f7053b80, 0x0)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/pam_fscrypt/run_fscrypt.go:82 +0x1f5 fp=0xc420123e40 sp=0xc420123da8 pc=0x7f3844efeb65
main.pam_sm_chauthtok(0x5639f704f110, 0x2000, 0x5639f7053b80, 0xc42006aed8)
    /build/fscrypt-ou7_LN/fscrypt-0.2.2/_build/src/github.com/google/fscrypt/pam_fscrypt/pam_fscrypt.go:288 +0x6a fp=0xc420123e78 sp=0xc420123e40 pc=0x7f3844efe93a
main._cgoexpwrap_058fc3b736e8_pam_sm_chauthtok(0x5639f704f110, 0x2000, 0x5639f7053b80, 0x45c044c992e60b00)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:114 +0x47 fp=0xc420123ea8 sp=0xc420123e78 pc=0x7f3844efd0c7
runtime.call32(0x0, 0x7ffd8a44f920, 0x7ffd8a44f9b0, 0x20)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:573 +0x3d fp=0xc420123ed8 sp=0xc420123ea8 pc=0x7f3844df844d
runtime.cgocallbackg1(0x0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/cgocall.go:316 +0x1a0 fp=0xc420123f58 sp=0xc420123ed8 pc=0x7f3844da7a60
runtime.cgocallbackg(0x0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/cgocall.go:194 +0xe0 fp=0xc420123fc0 sp=0xc420123f58 pc=0x7f3844da7820
runtime.cgocallback_gofunc(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:826 +0x9a fp=0xc420123fe0 sp=0xc420123fc0 pc=0x7f3844df9a5a
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361 +0x1 fp=0xc420123fe8 sp=0xc420123fe0 pc=0x7f3844dfac31
Aborted
```

This is the first time I have tried to change my password in over a year, and nothing else has changed with the system.

Comment: The fact that it seems to be erroring out with `go` code, suggests something is really wrong, probably with `pam`. From the output, I would be deleting anything from `go` & `fscrypt` as a start.

Comment: I've posted another question with a different issue that's come up today, and I have a feeling they're probably related, although I don't know how (unless my original password needed to be the same as something else for things to work)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677050/cannot-touch-home-user-ssh-known-hosts-required-key-not-available

Comment: I really doubt it would make a difference, but just in case, can you run `passwd myusername` without `sudo`? You don't need sudo to change your own password, and that would help clarify which part of this is giving the problem.